# git line-ending issues in macos

Tags: git, macos, line-endings

I am developing the application in multiple OS (Mac OS and Windows)

In windows everything works fine, but in mac i am not able to proceed because of end of line problems. When I open `.js` file in MACBOOK, it is having extra characters. My code is available in git and my `.gitattributes` file content

```
*       text=auto
```

I tried to do many trial and error and could not succeed.

**WINDOWS**

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

**MACBOOK**

```
git config --global core.autocrlf native
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 3):

It should be enough to set `text=auto` option for all files in your `.gitattributes` file. This option will make all text files (autodetected as such by `git`) to have normalized (LF) line endings in the repository. No need to set `core.autocrlf` option in this case. Read "End-of-line conversion" section of [gitattributes](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html) man page for details.

However you are missing an important step. After setting `text=auto` option you should normalize all the files that are already in your repository. It means that all text files with CRLF endings in you repository should have their line endings converted.

This are steps that should be performed on a clean working directory, as listed in the man page:

```
$ rm .git/index     # Remove the index to force git to
$ git reset         # re-scan the working directory
$ git status        # Show files that will be normalized
$ git add -u
$ git add .gitattributes
$ git commit -m "Introduce end-of-line normalization"
```

Pay attention to the changed files listed by `git status`. If any files have been falsely detected as text files you will have to manually exclude them from autoconversion in `.gitattributes` file, e.g.:

```
example.bin      -text
```

Comment: Thanks, i currently done with command as temporary solution, will come back to this solution very soon.